# Java multiple generics in interface and classes

Tags: java, openjdk-12

I'm working in a complex project with a lot of extensions and a lot generics. We use open jdk 12.

The objects I'm working on are:

```
public abstract class Node<C extends Node, P extends Property, A extends AuthorizationEntry> 

public abstract class Device<D extends Device, DP extends DeviceProperty> extends Node<D, DP, DeviceAuthorizationEntry>
```

The interface:

```
public interface NodeValidatorService<P extends Property, A extends AuthorizationEntry, C extends Node<C, P, A>>
```

The abstract class:

```
public abstract class AbstractNodeValidatorService<P extends Property, A extends AuthorizationEntry, C extends Node<C, P, A>> implements NodeValidatorService<P, A, C>
```

The implementation:

```
public class DeviceValidationServiceBean<D extends Device, DP extends DeviceProperty> extends AbstractNodeValidatorService<DP, DeviceAuthorizationEntry, D>
```

This last class is the one not compiling, due to:

> type argument D is not within bounds of type-variable C

I'm wondering if in DeviceValidationServiceBean I cannot add a further generic or if generics cannot recognize that even if D does not extends directly Node, it is still a Node itself too.
Can you explain what I did wrong or if it cannot simply be done that kind of multiple extensions on generics?

Comment: Hint: With `C extends Node` you are opting out of generics because here `Node` is just a raw type!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `AbstractNodeValidatorService` is declared with this as the last extend:

```
 C extends Node<C, P, A>> implements NodeValidatorService<P, A, C>
```

So it expects a `C` implementation as the last param.

But your `AbstractNodeValidatorService` is finishing with a `D`:

```
extends AbstractNodeValidatorService<DP, DeviceAuthorizationEntry, D> //this
```

`D` is unrelated to `C`, so D can't be the last param of the `AbstractNodeValidatorService`, but a `C` type class.